# Where is the application logic in a Java Web Start deployment?

Tags: java, security

Where does the application logic run in a Java Web Start deployment?  I want to understand the intellectual property security risk of Java Web Start.  On the client end does it merely start the application on a server and then proceed to process pixels (GUI objects) and mouse clicks at the client? or is my application logic executing at the client?

Implicit in my question is the assumption that I place no value on any aspects of the design that can be inferred by looking at the GUI buttons, text output and by being an experienced user of the application.  The value is in the code and logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically JWS keeps local .jar in sync with that on a server to execute an application in local mode. Read about JNLP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start).

So the risk for reverse engineering is the same as with any jar packet Java app.

Answer (score 1):

Java Web Start downloads code to the client, and executes it there. The application logic will execute at the client.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Java Web Start downloads the latest jars (Application Logic) from the server when u launch it with the help of JNLP. and then it installs this application in temporary internet files or cache.
Your whole application logic(cache) exists in cache at client side. and then your jnlp file use them (jars)